# Member count not refreshing, only on bot restart - discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I've created a bot with discord.js. I made a member counter to show the member count on voice channels and on my bot's activity.
My problem is that the counter only updates whenever I restart the bot, even tho in my console I get all the logs.

This is my code.

````js
    const membersOnline = guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence.status !== 'offline' && !member.user.bot).size;
    const humanMembers = guild.members.cache.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size;
    const memberCount = guild.memberCount;
    const customerCount = guild.roles.resolve('853015007532023859').members.size;
    const channel1 = guild.channels.cache.get('853276389474172958');
    const channel2 = guild.channels.cache.get('853298306753888257');

    // member counter

    setInterval(() =>{
        channel1.setName(`Members: ${humanMembers}`);
        channel2.setName(`Customers: ${customerCount.toLocaleString()}`);
        console.log('Refreshing member count');
        

        // bot presence 

         if(guild) {
             client.user.setPresence({activity: {name: `${humanMembers.toLocaleString()} users | beta 1.3.0` , type: 'WATCHING'}, status: 'online' })};
            }, 30000);
    ```
````

Comment: You need to move the declaration of `humanMembers` inside the `setInterval`'s callback to get an updated value each time.

Comment: you should do  as @ZsoltMeszaros said and don't forget to change `const` to `let`

Comment: @AhmedBenn It can still be const.  If he is moving the whole declaration to setInterval, it's a new instance created each time the method is called and it's never changed.  It then gets disposed as soon as setInterval is done executing.

Comment: Also, in addition to Zsolt's change, you need to move your customerCount as well.